# Exception Safety: Benefits of a nothrow swap

Tags: c++, exception, swap

If a type has a swap function which cannot fail, this can make it easier for other functions to provide the [strong exception safety guarantee](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/059.htm). This is because we can first do all of the function's work which may fail "off to the side", and then commit the work using non-throwing swaps.

However, are there any other benefits of guaranteeing that swap will never fail?

For example, is there a situation in which the presence of a no-fail swap makes it easier for another function to provide the *basic* guarantee?

Comment: There's always a benefit to avoiding Murphy's Law whenever possible...

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I do this:

```
class C {
  T a, b;  // invariant: a > b
  void swap(C& other);
};
```

It seems that there's no way to implement C::swap() with basic guarantee if T::swap(T&) might throw. I'd have to add a level of indirection and store T* instead of T.